# HTML link to create a bookmark does not work on first click but works on second click

Tags: html

I have the following HTML document -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p><a href="#C20">Jump to chapter20</a></p>
   
    <h2>Chapter1</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter2</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter3</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter4</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter5</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter6</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter7</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter8</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter9</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter10</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter11</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter12</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter13</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter14</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter15</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter16</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter17</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter18</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter19</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter20</h2>
    <p id="C20">This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open my document in google-chrome browser, I get a webpage. Its screenshot is -

[image]

Here the URL is:

**http://127.0.0.1:46661/1.html**

When I click on the link nothing happens.

The screenshot -

[image]

Here the url has changed to **http://127.0.0.1:46661/1.html#C20**

Whwn I again click on the link it works this time.

Screenshot -

[image]

The URL remains the same.

Why is my browser showing this weird behaviour?

Comment: The code you have presented works for me in Chrome, the page moves to Chapter 20 on the first click.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04, google Chrome, Brackets live mode

Comment: It may be an artefact (or bug) of Brackets, or another plug in, but the code is fine. Try the code in another browser or outside of Brackets.

Comment: Thanks you are correct, outside of brackets live mode the code works correctly

Answer (score -1):

Try the following.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p><a href="#C20">Jump to chapter20</a></p>

    <h2>Chapter1</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter2</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter3</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter4</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter5</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter6</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter7</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter8</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter9</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter10</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter11</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter12</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter13</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter14</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter15</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter16</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter17</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter18</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2>Chapter19</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>

    <h2 id="C20">Chapter20</h2>
    <p>This chapter explains bla bla bla</p>
</body>
</html>
```